# word printout call is blocking?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, ms-word, blocking

i am using adobe pdf as the active printer when calling the printout method of the word document to convert word document to PDF. Is the call blocking i.e. does the execution freeze at the call of method printout until the conversion process completes. the printout method when used with "Adobe PDF" as the active printer causes "Adobe Distiller" process to be launched. But i am not sure if the method call waits the process to exit. also so, far i see that the code is not blocking causing some file copy operations to fail.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237242%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you set the "Background" parameter to "False", the PrintOut method will be blocking but that still won't ensure that the conversion process has completed.  The conversion process may continue after the document has been completely sent to the "Adobe PDF" printer.

I'm not aware of a method to detect when the "Adobe PDF" printer has completed the converstion, but a different PDF writer does have a method to detect when processing has been completed (see [Detecting when Win2PDF has finished](http://www.win2pdf.net/helpdesk/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=105&nav=0,4)).